# Is it possible to share data between two DataWindowChild controls?

Tags: powerbuilder

In Powerbuilder window application, we can share data between two `DataWindow` controls.

Can the same be applied to two `DataWindowChild`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use the GetChild function to initialize the DataWindowChild variables and then use the ShareData function to share data. All the involved objects must have matching resultsets. Also, uncheck AutoRetrieve on the main DataWindow object.

Answer (score 0):

There are different techniques for doing this depending upon what functionality you wish to have between your two datawindows.  With the ShareData method if you change the data in one datawindow (either the Primary or Secondary) it changes in the other.

If you need to have a 'duplicate' set of data on separate datawindows you can use the Rowscopy method (which allows for the copying of all or some rows between the datawindows).

Another technique you can use utilizes the ImportString method.
To illustrate:

```
string ls_data
//save tab delimited string containing the data
ls_data = dw_1.object.datawindow.data //already contains data desired
dw_2.importstring(ls_data) //imports the data from dw_1
```

With this technique it is easiest if the two datawindows use the same datawindow object but this doesn't have to be the case (you must match the order and datatypes between the two).